# Proper memory management with CFStringRef and CFRelease

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

Consider this simple method; it's a category on NSString.

```
- (NSString *)stringByUrlEncoding
{
    CFStringRef newString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    NSString *returnString = (__bridge NSString *)newString;
    CFRelease(newString);
    return returnString;
}
```

Its job is to turn `=` into `%3D`, etc. for URL encoding, but that's not relevant to this question.

A few questions about memory management:

1. After `CFRelease(newString);` is called, I can still `po newString` in the debugger and see the string.  Does this mean it's not getting deallocated properly?
2. When I pass casted CFStringRefs to arguments of CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes, (like `(CFStringRef)self`, for example) I believe that I do NOT need to store those to a variable and then CFRelease them due to "toll-free bridging".  Is this correct?
3. Does the answer to #2 change if it's a CGImageRef, not a CFStringRef?  Why does CGImageRef have its own CGImageRelease function, but there's no CFStringRelease method?
4. To make sure my understanding of `__bridge_transfer` is correct, is this modified code identical?

   ```
   - (NSString *)stringByUrlEncoding
   {
       CFStringRef newString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
       NSString *returnString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)newString;
       // CFRelease(newString);
       return returnString;
   }
   ```

Comment: You might find it easier to use CFBridgingRelease than __bridge_transfer, since it makes it more clear what's happening. (ie. it's effectively releasing it.)

Comment: +1 for the question as helped me to understand the `__bridge` cast better. I would have bet that the first version does not work (but it does).

Comment: The `__bridge` version may happen to not crash in his testing, but it's actually incorrect. `__bridge` says "do no memory management at all." So it perfectly legal for `returnString` to be a dangling pointer here.

Comment: Note that that's by spec (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts). It says it does not insert any retain operations....BUT.... if you look at the actual output of clang, it does insert an objc_retain() and saves you even if you do it wrong. In debug, the generated assembler is identical. In release, the __bridge_transfer is more efficient (it skips the extra redundant retain/release).

Comment: @RobNapier Doesn't `__bridge` mean don't do any management on the CF side?  (Which is why I call CFRelease.)  I think ARC still handles `returnString` - I couldn't call `[returnString release]` if I wanted to.

Comment: @RobNapier ("ARC inserts no retain operations" on the cast operation, but `NSString *returnString` creates a strong pointer with +1 retain count.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your questions:

1) You don't have enough information to know if `newString` should have been deallocated.  For instance, if no character replacement was actually needed, it would be reasonable for `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to return you the equivalent of `[self retain]`; This is but one example. The broader point is "you can't know."  The normal approach here would be to use Instruments to look for heap growth and leaks. For more information, google "retainCount useless" (I won't rehash it here.)

2) Yes.

3) `CGImageRef` is not toll-free bridged, however, as I understand it, `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` should work. The difference between `CFRelease` and `CGImageRelease` here is that the parameter to `CFRelease` must not be `NULL`, whereas `CGImageRelease` will tolerate `NULL` parameters.

4) `__bridge_transfer` is the appropriate annotation to use here. This "transfers" the +1 retain count from the side that ARC doesn't handle to the side it does handle. Put differently, `__bridge_transfer` just tells ARC that it will need to create a `release` call for this pointer, even through it never generated a `retain`.

Comment: The last point is not correct: After `NSString *returnString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)newString;` you must not call `CFRelease(newString)`.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes; both snippets are fine.